# How to change default rendering error message before input in symfony framework?

Tags: symfony1, input, default

I want to change this default behaviour. I know that this could be done by extending `sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter` but then in all forms I must use `setFormatterName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sfProjectConfiguration` class, located in `/config`, override the `setup()` function, adding `sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName('your-class-name');` and it will be used by all forms